# Verify if string exists in an List

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a list with "Owners". I need to check if the current user is the owner.
so i tried  :  (list.Contains(string)) :

```
    string Owner = user.Name.ToString();
    if (lstOwners.Contains(Owner))
    {
        btnManager.Visible = true;
    } //does not work.
```

It doesn't work !!

but it works when i do that :

```
    if (lstOwners.Contains("BRJesusCA2"))
    {
        btnManager.Visible = true;
    }
```

can you please tell me why ??

Owner and "BRJesusCA2" have the same value!

Comment: What is 'user.Name'? Make sure the upper/lower case matches.

Comment: Why are you calling `ToString()`?

Comment: are you sure Owner is actually present in the list ?

Comment: When debugging are you sure that user.Name.ToString() = "BRJesusCA2" ?

Comment: @kostasch. yes! Owner is "BRJesusCA2", user.Name.ToString()  is the same as "BRJesusCA2"

Comment: What happens if you add this line of code: `Trace.Assert(user.Name.ToString() == "BRJesusCA2");` ?

Comment: Whitespaces? `"BRJesusCA2" != "BRJesusCA2 "`, but very hard to see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C# is case sensitive

```
bool contains = lstOwners.Contains(Owner, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
btnManager.Visible = contains;
```

Since you've asked for a collection that is more efficient. With 90 items that is mirco-optimization. However, you can replace it with a [`HashSet<string>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx):

```
HashSet<string> owners = new HashSet<string>(lstOwners, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
bool isOwner = owners.Contains(Owner);
```

The `HashSet<T>` class provides high-performance set operations. A set is a collection that contains no duplicate elements, and whose elements are in no particular order.

Comment: Tks, Tim! Now works! An list with all Owners is the best method to make an verification? For example, I have 90 owners in my List, to the best performance, have other method better then it?

Comment: You should use a database. However, if you don't want to use one or you don't have one you can use a `HashSet<string>` which is more efficient. But that is not an issue with 90 items.

Comment: If you are not using the bool contains anywhere else you could simplify this to one line and just make it btnManager.Visible = lstOwners.Contains(Owner, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);  If however you wanted to check later on that contains again use the above solution without having to have loops performed more than once behind the scenes.

Comment: @Tim I built this List with database. My question about performance is because now I have 90, but in some days I would have more than 5000 owner or more!

Comment: @CaioVJesus89: Edited my answer to show the `HashSet` approach.

Comment: @CaioVJesus89: Btw, was the case really the reason for this issue? Since you have mentioned in your question that ... _"Owner and "BRJesusCA2" have the same value"_. So was `user.Name.ToString()` actually lowercase/uppercase username?